# How to prevent urllib2 from following redirects on http requests?

Tags: python, urllib2

I am using the following recipe for getting the HTTP response code but it fails to get 3xx ones.

```
import urllib2
for url in ["http://entrian.com/", "http://entrian.com/does-not-exist/"]:
    try:
        connection = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        print connection.getcode()
        connection.close()
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e.getcode()
```

How can I disable the redirect processing on urllib2?

Comment: Perhaps [this page](http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/redirects.html) might help.

Answer (score 4):

You can make a subtype of [HTTPRedirectHandler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#httpredirecthandler-objects) that handles each redirect response code in whatever way you want. You then can use [urllib2.build_opener](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.build_opener) to build your custom redirect handler into the opener and overwrite the default redirect handler that way.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a direct answer - but in this case, you're much better off using [requests](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests)

```
import requests
for url in ["http://entrian.com/", "http://entrian.com/does-not-exist/"]:
    print requests.head(url).status_code
```